# c++ expression value (operator precedence)

Tags: c++, operator-precedence, conditional-operator, prefix-operator

The following expression :-

```
int main()
{
    int x=2, y=9;
    cout << ( 1 ? ++x, ++y : --x, --y);
}
```

gives the following output:-

```
9
```

As per my understanding, it should return ++y which should be 10. What went wrong?

Comment: unclear why you expect ++y as output. I could understand --y, but ++y is part of the condition not the output

Comment: Write it like this: `(1 ? ++x, ++y : (--x, --y))`. That ought to do what you're looking for. The grouping here is a bit peculiar, as the current answer indicates.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: OP expects `1 ? (++x, ++y) : (--x, --y)`...

Comment: @Jarod42 oh well, I completely misread the conditional. Its a nice way to write unreadable code ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence),

`1 ? ++x, ++y : --x, --y`

is parsed as

`(1 ? ++x, ++y : --x), --y`

Comment: An explanation about [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) would be helpful here.

Answer (score 5):

The ternary operator (`?` and `:`) has higher precedence compared to the comma operator (`,`). So, the expression inside the ternary conditional is evaluated first and then the statements are split up using the comma operator.

`1 ? ++x, ++y : --x, --y`

essentially becomes

```cpp
   (1 ? (++x, ++y) : (--x)), (--y)
/* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ is evaluated first by the compiler due to higher position in
                            the C++ operator precedence table */
```

You can eliminate the problem by simply wrapping the expression in parentheses:

`1 ? (++x, ++y) : (--x, --y)`

This forces the compiler to evaluate the expression inside the parentheses first without any care for operator precedence.